# filtering a data frame in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a data frame as follows:

```
dic ={'wteam': [2, 3, 4, 2, 4], 'lteam': [3, 4, 2, 4, 2]}
pd.DataFrame(dic) 

   lteam  wteam
0    3      2
1    4      3
2    2      4
3    4      2
4    3      4
```

I need a new data frame which has 2 in lteam or wteam.

```
        lteam  wteam
    0    3      2
    2    2      4
    3    4      2
```

How do I do this in pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your output from your starting df is wrong, the last row should be [2,4], aside from that we can call `loc` on the index generated by a boolean filtered df plus drop any `NaN` values:

```
In [15]:

df.loc[df[df==2].dropna(thresh=1).index]
Out[15]:
   lteam  wteam
0      3      2
2      2      4
3      4      2
4      2      4
```

Breaking this down:

```
In [16]:

df[df==2]
Out[16]:
   lteam  wteam
0    NaN      2
1    NaN    NaN
2      2    NaN
3    NaN      2
4      2    NaN
In [17]:

df[df==2].dropna(thresh=1)
Out[17]:
   lteam  wteam
0    NaN      2
2      2    NaN
3    NaN      2
4      2    NaN
```

A more succinct method would be to supply 2 boolean conditions:

```
In [18]:

df[(df.lteam == 2) | (df.wteam == 2)]
Out[18]:
   lteam  wteam
0      3      2
2      2      4
3      4      2
4      2      4
```

This requires using the bitwise `|` operator and brackets around the conditions due to operator precedence

The first method would be better if you have lots of columns but for your simple dataset then the latter method would be fine.

Comment: what is the difference between | and or

Comment: You can't use `or` with arrays, if you try this you get an error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` this is because you are trying to compare all the values but it's ambiguous if say one or more value matches, see this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/gotchas.html